# Get hour, minitues, seconds from NSCalendar components? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get hour, minitues, seconds from NSCalendar:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let units = NSCalendarUnit.Hour | NSCalendarUnit.Minute | NSCalendarUnit.Second
    let components = calendar?.components(units, fromDate: NSDate())
    var hours = components.hour
    var min = components.minute
    var sec = components.second
```

and

```
// This line is error, How to get the units ?
units = NSCalendarUnit.Hour | NSCalendarUnit.Minute | NSCalendarUnit.Second
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = calendar?.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate())
var hours = components?.hour
var min = components?.minute
var sec = components?.second
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because it expects Set of options, try this:

```
[NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second]
```